# SQL: How to get both match and non-match records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with following fields.

1. OrderId
2. ItemId

My table has following entries.

[image]

I want to compare both OrderIds and get a result to know what the ItemIds are existing in both Orders and what are not.

The result I need is below.

[image]

ItemId: 200 exists in both orders.

ItemId: 201 exists in 100, not in 101

ItemId: 202 and 203 exists in 101, not in 100.

I am not sure if this can be done via SQL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

SQL Scripts for testing:

`Create table #Orders(OrderId INT, ItemId INT)
Insert into #Orders Select 100, 200
Insert into #Orders Select 100, 201
Insert into #Orders Select 101, 200
Insert into #Orders Select 101, 202
Insert into #Orders Select 101, 203`

Comment: "I am not sure if this can be done via SQL" - almost everything you ever wanted to do can be done in SQL^^

Comment: will it always be two orders?  Do you want to compare all combinations of two orders?

Comment: Yes. i want to compare two orders.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you can do. Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. Use an image only to augment text or give what cannot be given via text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `CROSS JOIN` followed by a `LEFT JOIN` to check for availability.

Your desired output isn't the best for checking this when you have multiple orders and items, the following output should be good enough:

```
;WITH AllOrders AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT O.OrderID FROM #Orders AS O
),
AllItems AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT O.ItemId FROM #Orders AS O
)
SELECT
    OrderId = O.OrderId,
    ItemId = I.ItemId,
    IsItemInOrder = CASE WHEN A.OrderId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    AllOrders AS O
    CROSS JOIN AllItems AS I
    LEFT JOIN #Orders AS A ON
        O.OrderId = A.OrderId AND
        I.ItemId = A.ItemId
ORDER BY
    O.OrderId,
    I.ItemId
```

Results:

```
OrderId ItemId  IsItemInOrder
100     200     1
100     201     1
100     202     0
100     203     0
101     200     1
101     201     0
101     202     1
101     203     1
```

Comment: Awesome, that helps. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One way...

```
DECLARE @O1 INT = 100, @O2 INT = 101;

SELECT FirstOrderID = @O1, 
       SecondOrderId = @O2, 
       FirstOrderItemId = MAX(CASE WHEN OrderId =@O1 THEN ItemId END), 
       SecondOrderItemId = MAX(CASE WHEN OrderId =@O2 THEN ItemId END)
FROM  #Orders 
WHERE OrderId IN (@O1, @O2)
GROUP BY ItemId
```

Comment: Awesome, Working as expected. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want this for two orders, you can do:

```
select coalesce(oi1.orderid, 100), coalesce(oi2.orderid, 101), oi1.itemid, oi2.itemid
from (select oi.*
      from orderitems oi
      where oi.orderid = 100
     ) oi1 full join
     (select oi.*
      from orderitems oi
      where oi.orderid = 101
     ) oi2
     on oi2.orderid <> oi1.orderid and
        oi2.itemid = oi1.itemid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e42be18d316dcd62db4e50e9e91314b) is a db<>fiddle.

This answers the question that you asked.  If you want to generalize this to more orders, please ask another question.  This does not generalize quite as easily as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `CROSS JOIN` ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Orderid, tt.ItemID
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ItemId FROM table t1) t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table tt
     ON tt.Orderid = t.Orderid AND t1.Itemid = tt.ItemId;
```

For your desired result you would need more dynamic approach if you compare one or more orderids. So, `CROSS JOIN` would helpful in that scenario to look up no-matched itemids.

Comment: Thanks, That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As you write: *"I want to compare both OrderIds and **get a result to know what the ItemIds are existing in both Orders** and what are not."*

Just use an `INNER JOIN`- the resultset will include all ItemIDs which are in both orders:

```
      SELECT A.ItemID
        FROM dbo.yourtable A
  INNER JOIN dbo.yourtable B
          ON A.ItemID        = B.ItemID
         AND B.OrderID       = 101
       WHERE A.OrderID       = 100
```

Comment: Thanks, That didn't help.